# Group dataframe columns in lists

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
| id | A  | B  | C  | D  |
| 1  | 50 | 51 | 52 | 53 |
| 2  | 70 | 71 | 72 | 73 |
| 1  | 80 | 81 | 82 | 83 |
| 1  | 90 | 91 | 92 | 93 |
| 2  | 40 | 41 | 42 | 43 |
```

I want to group it on 'id' column so that each row is in form of list.

Expected Output:

```
| id |      A     |      B     |      C     |      D     |
| 1  | [50,80,90] | [51,81,91] | [52,82,92] | [53,83,93] |
| 2  |   [70,40]  |   [71,41]  |   [72,42]  |   [73,43]  |
```

Explaination:
The values for id 1 in column A are all in one list similarly for other. The length of list depends on number of records of that id in initial dataframe.

My approach:

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(['id'])['A'].apply(lambda x: list(x)).reset_index().merge(df.groupby(['id'])['B'].apply(lambda x: list(x)).reset_index().merge(df.groupby(['id'])['C'].apply(lambda x: list(x)).reset_index().merge(df.groupby(['id'])['D'].apply(lambda x: list(x)).reset_index()),on=['id'],how='left'))
```

Although this gives me the desired output, but its slow for large dataframes and I feel this is not very optimal as well as we are grouping on id each time and merging.
There should be a way wherein I group on id once and do something columns.tolist() and it gives the same output.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
#all columns without id
df_grouped = df.groupby('id').agg(list).reset_index()
```

Or:

```
#columns specified in list
df_grouped = df.groupby('id')[['A','B','C','D']].agg(list).reset_index()

print (df_grouped)
   id             A             B             C             D
0   1  [50, 80, 90]  [51, 81, 91]  [52, 82, 92]  [53, 83, 93]
1   2      [70, 40]      [71, 41]      [72, 42]      [73, 43]
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great although it was surprising for me to note that the speed of my code and this aggregate function was in same range and not much different. The reason for my surprise being the fact that my code calls groupby('id') part 4 times and only once in this. \n 
Any thoughts on why this might be?

Comment: @Alex - Because he use `groupby.apply` and it processing each columns in dataframe together, but `groupby.agg` processing each columns separately. It means first A, then, b... and last D.